# ruby on rails app stuck on futex 'kill QUIT PID' but passenger gives no trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux-kernel, passenger, system-calls

Part of passenger-status(`nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.1`) output shows that the two processes are shutting down but cannot quit.

```
  * PID: 10351   Sessions: 1       Processed: 279777   Uptime: 6d 1h 41m 37s
    CPU: 3%      Memory  : 625M    Last used: 2d 3
    Shutting down...
  * PID: 10370   Sessions: 1       Processed: 290718   Uptime: 6d 1h 41m 37s
    CPU: 3%      Memory  : 778M    Last used: 6h 5
    Shutting down...
```

The strace output tells me the ruby process is stuck on futex call.

`$ strace -p 10351
strace: Process 10351 attached
futex(0x7fd7cbf02210, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL`

`kill -QUIT 10351` also gives me no trace info.

The relevant output of `ps -efL` to process 10351 shows another thread id 10353.

```
ubuntu   10351     1 10351  0    2 Feb02 ?        00:00:02 Passenger AppPreloader: /var/www/app/current (forking...)
ubuntu   10351     1 10353  0    2 Feb02 ?        00:00:00 Passenger AppPreloader: /var/www/app/current (forking...)
```

and `strace -p 10353` outputs:

```
strace: Process 10353 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>
```

Any idea how to get the ruby trace info to debug the issue?

Comment: did you found any solution for this, facing the same issue?